# Saving Audio File on SQL Server Management Studio using VB.net 2010

Tags: vb.net, database-connection, ssms

Please help me with this audio file saving on SQL server management studio connection.

I have a recorder on vb.net 2010 and i want to save my audio recorded in SQL and display it on DataGridview (vb.net 2010)  at the same time save it on my database which is SQL.

Please help me guys, what are the propably codes for this saving thing on database. Please do not use C# and C++ as a guide or source code. Only VB.net

Comment: I can only suggest to split your whole problem in small steps. Try to solve one writing something, then proceed with the next step. If you are stuck then come here with a practical problem to be solved. Did you expect  to get the full solution here?

Answer (score 2):

Create an Access Database in your D: drive and name it SoundDB.accdb
Create a table in the DB and name it tblSounds with 3 fields   sndid text(2), sndname text(20) , sndbinary OLEObject)

Create a new form in your project

Add a Textbox and 3 buttons.

Type an Id number (2 digits) in the textbox

button 1 will start recording

button2 will stop recording and save the sound to your DB

button3 will fetch from DB the sound for the ID you specify in the textbox and play it

---

Add these lines to the beginning of your code.

Imports System.IO

Imports System.Text

Imports System.Data.OleDb

---

Add this declaration to your code

Declare Function mciSendString Lib "winmm.dll" Alias "mciSendStringA" ( _
                                                                         ByVal lpstrCommand As String, _
                                                                         ByVal lpstrReturnString As StringBuilder, _
                                                                         ByVal uReturnLength As Integer, _
                                                                         ByVal hwndCallback As IntPtr) As Integer

---

Paste the Sub routines below into your code

```
Private Sub SaveSndtoDB(ByVal SndID As String, ByVal sndName As String)

    Dim Connection As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\SoundDB.accdb")

    Dim SndSourceStream As Stream = New FileStream("D:\FileName.wav", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)

    Dim BinarySndReader As New BinaryReader(SndSourceStream)
    Dim bytes As Byte() = BinarySndReader.ReadBytes(SndSourceStream.Length)

    Connection.Open()

    'insert the file into database
    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO tblSounds (sndid,sndname,sndbinary) VALUES ('" + SndID + "','" + sndName + "',@SndBinary)", Connection)

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SoundBinary", bytes)
    Try
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("File Uploaded Successfully")

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("There was a problem, file upload was not successful. " + ex.Message)
    End Try

    SndSourceStream.Flush()
    SndSourceStream.Close()

    FileClose()
    Reset()

    Application.DoEvents()

End Sub

Private Sub PlaySndfromDB(ByVal sndID As String)

    FileClose()
    Reset()

    Dim Connection As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\SoundDB.accdb")

    Dim SndSourceStream As Stream = New FileStream("D:\FileName.wav", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)

    Try
        Connection.Open()

        Dim command As New OleDbCommand("SELECT sndbinary FROM tblsounds WHERE sndID = @ID", Connection)


        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", sndID)

        Dim soundData As Byte() = DirectCast(command.ExecuteScalar(), Byte())

        Connection.Close()
        command.Dispose()

        SndSourceStream.Write(soundData, 0, soundData.Length)

        SndSourceStream.Flush()
        SndSourceStream.Close()

        My.Computer.Audio.Play("d:\FileName.wav", AudioPlayMode.Background)

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString())
    End Try


End Sub




Private Sub StartRecording()

    mciSendString("open new type waveaudio alias mywav", Nothing, 0, 0)
    mciSendString("record mywav", Nothing, 0, 0)

End Sub

Private Sub SaveRecording()

    mciSendString("stop mywav", Nothing, 0, 0)
    mciSendString("save mywav d:\FileName.wav", Nothing, 0, 0)
    mciSendString("close mywav", Nothing, 0, 0)

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    StartRecording()
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    SaveRecording()
    Application.DoEvents()
    SaveSndtoDB(TextBox1.Text, "Snd" + TextBox1.Text)

End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

    PlaySndfromDB(TextBox1.Text)

End Sub
```

================================================================================

Hope this helps, feel free to let me know if you need further help.
I have not tested this code with very long sound files, it works well with snippets.

Answer (score 0):

```
'create a table in SQL with feilds name F1,F2,F3 .... and Aud as image 
Dim path
path = "Data Source=SERVER\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog="DatabaseName";Integrated Security=True; " ';user=Uni;password=uni"
    Con.Open()
Public Sub InsertAudioDataInTable(TableName, TableMapingName, LoopStart, LoopEnd, TaxtName, Panel, AdioPath)
    Dim SndSourceStream As Stream = New FileStream(AdioPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)

    Dim BinarySndReader As New BinaryReader(SndSourceStream)
    Dim arrImage As Byte() = BinarySndReader.ReadBytes(SndSourceStream.Length)
    Dim strImage As String
    strImage = "@Aud"
    Dim b = 0
    Dim dataContaner(LoopEnd + 2 - LoopStart) As String
    For a = LoopStart To LoopEnd
        dataContaner(b) = Panel.Controls(TaxtName & a).Text.ToString
        b = b + 1
    Next
    ''''''''''''''
    Dim myCmd As New SqlCommand
    myCmd.Connection = Con
    ''''''''''
    Dim T As String
    '  T.Text = null
    Dim aaa = "INSERT INTO  " & TableName
    Dim bbb = ""
    For i = LoopStart To LoopEnd
        bbb = bbb + "F" & i & ","
    Next
    T = aaa & " (" + bbb & "Aud"
    '  T = T.Remove(T.Length - 1)
    T = T & ")VALUES ("

    Dim ccc = ""
    b = 0
    For a = LoopStart To LoopEnd
        ccc = ccc & "'" & dataContaner(b) & "',"
        b = b + 1
    Next
    T = T + ccc
    myCmd.CommandText = T + strImage & ")"
    myCmd.Parameters.Add(strImage, SqlDbType.Binary).Value = arrImage
    myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    ''''''''


End Sub
```